# Unknown problem with span positioning IE and some CSS

Tags: css, positioning, html

Well I have two buttons, each image in a span, and one should be positioned on top of the other, with the bottom one on top of some text, and all of it to the right of one big image. But in internet explorer the images and text do not stack.

Firefox:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo9SX.png

Internet Explorer:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cENPC.png

This is the current code:

```
    <span class="block">
        <img src="images/application.png" alt="Screenshot" width="569px" height="285px">
    </span>
    <span class="block">
        <a href="portable"><span id="button_portable"></span></a><br>
        <a href="installer"><span id="button_installer"></span></a><br>
        <a href="http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/B/E/1BE39E79-7E39-46A3-96FF-047F95396215/dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe"><span style="font-size:1em">(Requires .NET framework 4.0)</span></a><br><br>
        <a href="/changelog.php"><span style="font-size:1.3em">Changelog</span></a>
    </span>
```

And CSS:

```
    span.block {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 20px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    span[id="button_portable"], span[id="button_installer"] {
        background: url("images/download.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
        float: left;
        height: 70px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        width: 250px;
    }
    span#button_installer {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    span#button_installer:hover {
        background-position: 0 -71px;
    }
    span#button_portable {
        background-position: 0 -142px;
    }
    span#button_portable:hover {
        background-position: 0 -213px;
    }
```

I have looked up several changes and tried them all, but none of them seemed to work.

Comment: Is it too late to consider using CSS reset?

Comment: Not at all, although I've never used one before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `float: left;` with `display: inline-block;`.

See [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/D4WPz/3/).

Tested on Win7 in IE7, IE8, IE9, Chrome 12, FF 4.

Answer (score 0):

[Eric Meyer's CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) is usually regarded as the best CSS reset out there.

The purpose of CSS reset is to provide a "starting point" so that all browsers start off with the same defaults. This makes pages display similarly in different browsers without the need for specific hacks for each browser or particular CSS "bug" or difference you have between name-a-version-of-IE and every-single-other-browser

Comment: So I just place it above my current CSS?

Comment: Yes, usually you place it in your master page, or whatever you are using, but it needs to be the first rules.

Comment: I hadn't read your CSS, why do you have `span[id="button_portable"]`? I'm fairly certain IE doesn't support non-sense like that (I'm fairly certain IE doesn't support anything). Just use `span#button_portable, span#button_installer`

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, but alas, no effect.